# PHP preg_replace and explode function

Tags: php, preg-replace, explode

I have some raw data like this

```
\u002522\u00253A\u002522https\u00253A\u00255C\u00252F\u00255C\
```

My intention is to remove the backslash "\" and first 7 digit of every string between   \u002522https\ this. For this the output will be only https.

If there is only 7 digit like this  \u002522\ the output will be empty.

My final intention is to put every result in a array which is formatted for the above raw data like this

```
Array
(
      [0] => 
      [1] => 
      [2] => https
      [3] => 
      [4] => 
      [5] => 
      [6] => 


)
```

I want this result for constructing a URL. I have tried with `preg_replace` and `explode` function to get my expected result but I am failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = '\u002522\u00253A\u002522https\u00253A\u00255C\u00252F\u00255C\\';
$text = preg_replace("#(\\\\[a-z0-9]{7})#is",",",$text);
$text_array = explode(",",trim($text,'\\'));
print_r($text_array);
```